# how do I change background image of application based on url or routing?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to change the background image of the application(Html Body) based on the url. And this I want to do in angularJS only :)

For eg:

1) if user visits the url like this,

www.domain.com/**view1**

Bellow image is shown

[image]

2) If user visits url
  www.domain.com/**view2**

I want show other image

[image]

**app.js**

```
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  }])

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);;
```

**Controler.js**

```
 app.controller('MyCtrl1',function($scope){
    $scope.viewBackground="body"
    console.log($scope.viewBackground);
})

app.controller('MyCtrl2',function($scope){
    $scope.viewBackground="profile"
})
```

in the partial html, I am just doing like this

```
    <div class="span12">


            <p>

           {{$scope.viewBackground}}zxz
            </p>

    </div>
```

But some reason I am not able to get the value of **viewBackground** property value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but I hope so.
You have 2 options.

First - use different controllers for each page **view1** and **view2**.
And use ng-class directive on the pages:

**HTML**:

```
<!-- "page" View 1 -->
<div ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
    <div ng-class="viewBackground"> View 1 </div> 
</div>

<!-- "page" View 2 -->
<div ng-controller="View2Ctrl">
    <div ng-class="viewBackground"> View 2 </div> 
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function View1Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.viewBackground = "background-small"
}    

function View2Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.viewBackground = "background-big"
}
```

On your **CSS**:

```
.background-small{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background: url('...img1...');
}

.background-big{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
        background: url('...img2...');
}
```

Second option - use **.run** block, where you will add some logic to change the bg-image, but this is a poor option

Comment: I think it may work, but I got one binding issue. please see the edited question

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure that I can help you. But may be you can save property of background value to a rootScope or to a localstorage. In this case you be able to reach value from any controller. Actualy it's looks like an ugly hack, but perhaps it's helps

Answer (score 0):

If your controller you can check the $routeParams param and then set a scope variable to control the background image.

```
function announcements_detail_controller($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $http, $location)
{  //console.log($routeParams);
   $scope.css_class_for_background_image = 'xxxx';//

}
```